# Drupal with mentions

Tags: drupal, module, drupal-7

So I'm trying to enable mentions like on twitter in drupal. I wan't to be able to use @username in writing new content and in comments section. It should dispaly dropdown when you start typing so you can select a username from dropdown. I'm surprised there isn't any good modules for it out there. I finaly found At.js module, but can't get it to work.

I created new listener and here it's his export format:

```
$listener = new stdClass();
$listener->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default listener disabled initially */
$listener->api_version = 1;
$listener->name = 'atjs_test';
$listener->title = 'Atjs test';
$listener->entity_type = 'user';
$listener->bundles = array();
$listener->record_usage = FALSE;
$listener->at = '@';
$listener->tpl = '<li data-value="${atwho-at}${name}">${name}</li>';
$listener->insert_tpl = '<span>${atwho-data-value}</span>';
$listener->search_key = 'property:name';
$listener->data_to_supply = array(
  'uid' => 'uid',
  'name' => 'name',
  'created' => 'created',
  'status' => 'status',
  'language' => 'language',
  'pass' => 0,
  'mail' => 0,
  'theme' => 0,
  'signature' => 0,
  'signature_format' => 0,
  'access' => 0,
  'login' => 0,
  'timezone' => 0,
  'picture' => 0,
  'init' => 0,
  'data' => 0,
);
$listener->query_limit = TRUE;
$listener->max_length = TRUE;
```

Any ideas wha't am i doing wrong or sugestion on any other modules?

Comment: Apparently, there is a module that does that twitter-like mentions but it still in dev version for d7. Maybe this topic could help you http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/59512/mention-reply-to-users-in-comments-using-name

Comment: Yea i checked it out but it realy doesn't work well the link only get changed after the insert, but i wan't a dropdown select...